# Belong to x one of

Tags: meaning

Is it possible to use *he belongs to the greatest players* to mean *he is one of the greatest players*?

While I know that in other languages (including my own), these two are interchangeable, I feel that in English, although *belong* has a number of meanings, this one *does not belong to* them. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use *belong to* in this way in English.  You can use *numbered amongst* or *accounted one of*, but not *belong to*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did think so but you see it so often in various translations that I was beginning to think that I might not have understood it.

Comment: One way you could use _belong_ in this context would be: "_He belongs in the group of greatest players._"